# SecurityException: Only SystemUI can disable the safe media volumne : STATUS_BAR_SERVICE

Tags: android

When we are trying to set volume using below code

```
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
```

getting below error, only on one phone (dvn=Android_LenovoA6000)

```
CaughtException: java.lang.SecurityException: Only SystemUI can disable the safe media volume: Neither user 10134 nor current process has android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setStreamVolume(IAudioService.java:910)
    at android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:1083)
    at com.pkt.versant.viewControllers.CalibrationVolume$1.onProgressChanged(CalibrationVolume.java:129)
    at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:95)
```

Can anybody know why this error is coming and how i can resolve it.
Application is not system apk.

Comment: 1) You try to access an API that requires system signature 2) You can't solve it because your app isn't a system app (with system signature)

Comment: which API ? are you taking about This one mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);     getSystemService don't required system signature at all. I am running my app on different phone and running perfectly without any issue. I am getting this issue on only on Lenovo device right now.

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to happen only on Android 7+. No solution yet. Could this be related to the same problem as calling setRingerMode() that requires permission ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY ?

Comment: @Priti we have fixed that issue :D

Comment: @cubesoft : how? let me know.

Comment: @Benjamin Piette in my case Android_LenovoA6000 has OS version 5.0.2. and error coming on Lenovo device only

Comment: @cubesoft how to solve this issue. It's only happening in Lenovo

Comment: @cubesoft how did you solve it. I am getting this issue on lenovo device only

Comment: @cubesoft How have you solved it? I am facing same issues with Lenovo A6000 (Kraft-A6000), 1024MB RAM, Android 5.0

Comment: @Priti Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I have same problem on Lenovo A6010.

Comment: Maybe something related to Dolby Atmos, some system modification?